# Keyword Search Across All Servers - Powershell

Tags: powershell

Afternoon All,

I need to run a search across all of our servers.
I have the list of servers in a text document and a list of keywords in another

```
$Servers = get-content -path 'C:\support\Server Search\Server Test.txt'
$Keywords = get-content -path "C:\Support\Server Search\Keyword Test.txt"

Foreach ($Server in $Servers){
Foreach ($Keyword in $Keywords){

Get-ChildItem "$Server" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$Keyword"} 

$i++
Write-Host "$found: $i - Current $ $_"

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
Directory = $_.Directory
Name = $_.Name
Length = $_.Length /1024
CreationTime = $_.CreationTime
LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
LastAccessTime = $_.LastAccessTime}|
select Directory,Name,Length,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime |
Export-Csv "C:\support\server search\$Server.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}}   

$i = 0
```

Is there a way to indicate when a Keyword has been located and total keywords found? I feel like I need to change this Line but I cannot fathom what I would actually put, I've tried $Keywords but that just changes keyword everytime the directory changes

```
$i++
    Write-Host "$found: $i - Current $ $_"
```

Comment: Honestly, I can't even tell what your script does.  It's a mess.  Is `$Servers` just a list of server names, or a list of file shares?  If it's just server names, what are you expecting `Get-ChildItem "$Server" -Recurse` to do?  Do the keywords in `$Keywords` contain wildcard characters already?  If not, what are you expecting `Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$Keyword"}` to do that `-eq` wouldn't?  Aren't you missing a `| ForEach-Object { ...` after the `Where-Object`?

Comment: You have a number of `foreach` statements, but you then refer to `$_`, which has no meaning in a `foreach` statement.  You'd need to have a pipeline such as if you were using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.  Also, assuming `Get-ChildItem "$Server" -Recurse` is enumerating files, why are you enumerating the entire `$Server` for each keyword?  Why not enumerate the server once and then search for each keyword using the list of files already in memory, or search the entire list of keywords for each file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your $server is set up something like "\\servername\c$\"

> when a Keyword has been located and total keywords found:

```
$Servers = get-content -path 'C:\support\Server Search\Server Test.txt'
$Keywords = get-content -path "C:\Support\Server Search\Keyword Test.txt"

$num = 0  #Total Keyword files Found

Foreach ($Server in $Servers){
Foreach ($Keyword in $Keywords){
    #Keyword found Check
    $Found = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Server" -Recurse -Include "$Keyword"
    if($Found){
        Foreach($File in $Found){
            $num++   #increment num of keyword files found by 1        

            Write-Host "found: $num - $File"

            New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            Directory = $File.Directory
            Name = $File.Name
            Length = $File.Length /1024
            CreationTime = $File.CreationTime
            LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
            LastAccessTime = $File.LastAccessTime}|
            select Directory,Name,Length,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime |
            Export-Csv "C:\support\server search\$Server.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }    
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if this helps you progress. I can assist further if requested.